# Rake Task Require Files (non gem) - Where are they stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a rake task and I need to require a gem and two source files. I've used the bundle install to install the gem so that's not a problem, but what folder should I save my two source file to?  My rake task in in /lib/tasks/my_rake_task.rb.

Under rails convention, should the source files be saved there as well or is there a preferred  location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like any file loaded in the lib folders is loaded.